# How to make element scrollable?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a scrollbar in a div element.

So I try it like this:

```css
#roomlist {
  width: 250px;
  /* max-height: 100%; */
  /* overflow-y: hidden; */
  overflow: scroll;
  max-width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -210px;
  background-color: #91c7e1;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="roomlist">
  <div id='ex1'>
    <ul id="roomlistul"></ul>
  </div>
```

And yes you see the up arrow and down arrow. But you dont see the actual beam so that you can scroll. See image what I mean[image]

If I do it like this:

```
  <div id="roomlist">
          <div id='ex1'>
            <ul id="roomlistul"></ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and this:

```
#ex1 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

I don't see the scrollbar

Comment: you need to add a fixed height to your div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create css

```
.scroll-box {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 400px;
}
```

usage

```
<div class="scroll-box">
    <div>content height more than 400px</div>
</div>
```

once the content height is more than 400px, in this example, then scroll bar will appear.

Comment: Yes, Oke, I have to put in the #roomlist div

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use auto-scallable flex-containers;

demo layout:

```
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="scrollable-content">
    <p>I am Groot</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

demo styles:

```
.parent-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  // we want to put fixed height here, 
  // so scrollable-content scaled properly
  height: 200px; 
}

.scrollable-content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

in your case it would be:

```
#roomlist {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  max-width: 300px;
  // fixed height value
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: -210px;
  background-color: #91c7e1;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

#ex1 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: @codeIsNice you can assign `#roomlistul {height: 9999px}` and you will see scrolbar. The main point with scrollable flex, is that it will take full space of parent, and show scrollbar only if its bigger then parent height.